# UIImagePickerController Image returned is bigger than preview on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, image, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm taking a photo with UIImagePickerController. Everything works fine on iPad and on iPhone 5. The problem comes with an iPhone4: the photo that I get from the picker is "bigger" than what I saw on the screen when I took the photo.

What do I mean with bigger? I mean that at both sides of the photo, and at the bottom, I see parts of the scene that the camera didn't show when I was taking the photo. This is a problem for my app. I need to capture exactly the same scene that the user sees through the camera when he takes the photo. Not a bigger scene. As I said, on iPhone5 and iPad4 everything works fine. I don't understand this different behaviour. How can I solve this?

PD: I'm not applying any transformation to the image on the picker.

Comment: You could cut the image.

Comment: But that approach is very inexact. How do I know how much I have to cut? There must be another way...

Comment: `self.imgeView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;`

or UIViewContentModeCenter, or any of the other modes described in the UIView documentation.

Comment: @iosLearner that's not an answer to my question... I want to capture exactly what I see on the screen when I press the capture button. That's the normal behaviour of a camera. But on iPhone4 doesn't work this way, I don't know why. It's not a problem of the contentMode of a UIImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the preview on the iPhone4... the preview on the iPhone4 is 16:9, but the final image is 4:3. On the iPhone5 and the iPad, both the preview and the final image are 4:3.

I didn't realize it before because my overlay was hiding part of the preview on the iPhone4, so I thought the preview was 4:3 too (and I think that the preview with iOS6 is 4:3, I'm not sure, I've got to find an iPhone4 with iOS6).

I made my overlay (a UIToolbar) translucent, and now I get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController*)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary*)info
{
    UIImage* originalImage = [info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    NSLog(@"Image Size Width %f  Height %f",originalImage.size.width,originalImage.size.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 480));
    [originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSLog(@"image Size h %f  Width %f",[image size].height, [image size].width);

}
```

Here you can see that What is original image size and after than you can change size as your wish..

Comment: that doesn't resolve my problem, it's not a problem of size... originalImage on iPhone4 shows more scene than what I was seeing when I pressed the capture button. I could cut the originalImage, but how much? I can't compare with anything... I think that's not a good approach.